# KeyError looping through multiple values per key

Tags: python, dictionary, finance, keyerror

(This question may differ from "Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops" in that I have multiple entries for each key, and am also having issues 'pointing' to the right one).

There is this empty dictionary:

```
import .math

instruments = {}
```

The following simple method populates it:

```
 def add_instrument(par, T, coup, price, compounding_freq = 2):
      instruments[T] = (par, coup, price, compounding_freq)

add_instrument(100, 0.25, 0., 97.5)
add_instrument(100, 0.5, 0., 94.9)
add_instrument(100, 1.0, 3., 90.)
add_instrument(100, 1.5, 8, 96., 2)
```

If we check:

```
instruments.keys()
```

We obtain:   `[0.25, 0.5, 1.5, 1.0]`

I would then like to loop through the dictionary and `if coup == 0`, do certain operation, else do something else:

```
for T in instruments.items():
    (par, coupon, price, freq) = instruments[T]
    if coupon == 0:
          do_something
```

But I am getting a `#KeyError: (0.25, (100, 0.0, 97.5, 2))`

Any idea why and how should i re-arrange the loop? TIA.

## Edit: using the answer below, the BootstrapYieldCurve class works as planned, on the book 'Mastering Python for Finance', ch5.

Comment: `for T in instruments.items():` should be `for T in instruments.keys():` or just `for T in instruments:`

Comment: what happens when you change for `T in instruments.items():`  to `for T, _ in instruments.items():` also, I believe, you should write `global instruments` inside your add_instruments function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is the key, so you should iterate with `for T in instruments`:

```
import math

instruments = {} 

def add_instrument(par, T, coup, price, compounding_freq = 2):
  instruments[T] = (par, coup, price, compounding_freq)

add_instrument(100, 0.25, 0., 97.5)
add_instrument(100, 0.5, 0., 94.9)
add_instrument(100, 1.0, 3., 90.)
add_instrument(100, 1.5, 8, 96., 2)

for T in instruments:
    par, coupon, price, freq = instruments[T]
    if coupon == 0:
        print(T)
```

If you use `for T in instruments.items()`, `T` becomes a tuple of `(key, value)`. When you then look for `instruments[T]`, there's no such key in the dict.

You could also unpack the value tuple directly if you insist on using `items()`:

```
for t, (par, coup, price, freq) in instruments.items():
    if coup == 0:
        print(t)
```

It outputs:

```
0.25
0.5
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, this finally works. And indeed, I was having an issue with unpacking the 3rd element when using instruments.keys() instead of instrumetns.items() .